# ActionBar not showing menu items

Tags: android

I have a `main.xml` defined as:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        android:title="@string/notifications" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reportsView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reports"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/reportsView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/userProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:title="@string/userProfile" />
</menu>
```

And in activity I have this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

But still I cant see buttons on my action bar. Can anybody tell what am I missing

`styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />

</resources>
```

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: i have updated my question its `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: You are trying to inflate **main.xml**, not menu.xml: `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`. Either rename menu.xml as `main.xml` **or** change the infaltion to `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);`.

Comment: actually it was a typo in the question, my bad i ahve corrected it.

Comment: See what `@style/AppTheme` refers to (inside styles.xml).

Comment: You're missing some nameSpaces, mainly `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. So to use these attributes in your items: `app:showAsAction="always"|never|asNeeded`

Comment: I have added the code in `styles.xml` please check

Comment: wait wats your minimum target? are you using support library? which api level did you test on?

Comment: minSdkVersion 14 and targetSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 0):

The items don't appear in your ActionBar, because you didn't explicitly tell them to be visible:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

<strike>If you're using activity class from the support package (e.g. `ActionBarActivity`), you also need to use a custom namespace like this:</strike>

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/notifications" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reportsView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reports"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/reportsView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/userProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/userProfile" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Tried, and have updated the code with this but still no change

Comment: @Maven what activity class do you extend?

Comment: I have two activities one extended from `FragmentActivity` and other from `Activity` problem is same in both.

Comment: @Maven and what's your `minSdk`?

Comment: @DerGolem that would throw an error, as you must use `AppCompat` theme then.

Comment: `minSdkVersion 14` and `targetSdkVersion 19`

Comment: @Maven please try using the Holo theme: `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">`, because Theme.Light is meant for APIs 10 and lower.

Comment: @Maven also note that you won't need to use a custom namespace as suggested in my answer.

Comment: changed the theme but still same.

Comment: @Maven weird, your setup works fine for me. Try to create a new project and see if the problem repeats itself.

Answer (score 0):

this is not really persuasive but override this too..

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true  //return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Or clean your project.. restart..do all of that